# SelectLayerByAttribute not renwing before CopyFeatures

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 and want a python script to loop through a list to make new feature classes, using the list items as attribute values in a selection before copying the features to a new file.

The script makes the first feature class fine but then copies all of the features for the next two iterations of the loop.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\RS_Data\SHP"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

amenities = ['school', 'hospital', 'place_of_worship']
points = r"C:\RS_Data\SHP\OSMpoints.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "OSM_Lyr")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("OSM_Lyr","amenity") as cursor:
    for amenity in amenities:
        query3 = '"amenity" = ' + "'" + amenity + "'"
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("OSM_Lyr", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == amenity:
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("OSM_Lyr", "ADD_TO_SELECTION",query3)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("OSM_Lyr", amenity)
        print query3
```

Here is the print statement I get for the query after each loop:

```
"amenity" = 'school'
"amenity" = 'hospital'
"amenity" = 'place_of_worship'
```

It seems the selection is working the first time but not for the next two iterations. If I take the CLEAR_SELECTION line out it makes three identical feature classes using the same attribute value. How can I get the loop to make a selection on the next value in the list and copy the features to a new file?

Comment: Instead of using MakeFeatureLayer_management, SelectLayerByAttribute_management, CopyFeatures_management and an arcpy.da.SearchCursor I think you should investigate the Select_analysis tool which should bring this down to about 5 lines of code.  Just iterate through your list of values and feed them to Select_analysis.

Comment: Or the where clause on the search cursor... Not that I can see why you're using a cursor here. To me it seems like you should loop through your amenities (like you are) and Select like PolyGeo said, MakeFeatureLayer with where_clause or SelectLayerByAttribute and copy features - no need for a cursor here at all.

Comment: and no need for MakeFeatureLayer or SelectLayerByAttribute or CopyFeatures either - Select_analysis() replaces all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) as @PolyGeo and @Michael Miles-Stimson say will indeed simplify your code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\RS_Data\SHP"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

amenities = ['school', 'hospital', 'place_of_worship']
points = r"C:\RS_Data\SHP\OSMpoints.shp"

for amenity in amenities:
    query3 = '"amenity" = ' + "'" + amenity + "'"
    arcpy.Select_analysis(points, amenity, query3)
```

For the rest your code with cursor and layers looks right, you should maybe replace `"ADD_TO_SELECTION"` with `"NEW_SELECTION"` in the second `SelectLayerByAttribute` (and the first `SelectLayerByAttribute` will then become unnecessary).

Comment: I used Michael's solution as this is for a class assignment and we haven't covered Select_analysis yet, although it seems to me that this is an improvement over SelectLayerByAttribute by obviating the MakeFeatureLayer step. Thanks!